# How to create a media player in Java without JMF?

Tags: java, video, jmf

How to create a media player in Java without using the JMF?  Some blogs say it's an old version. I also tried using JMF - this is my code.

```
public class MediaPlayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Player p;
         try {
            p = Manager.createPlayer(new URL("http://192.168.1.113/asmitha/1.mp4"));
            p.start();
        } catch (NoPlayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the message I am getting:

```
LINEAR, Unknown Sample Rate * out * LINEAR, 8000.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, class [S
```

Answer (score 2):

JMF 2.1 is the latest version, and that was released a long time ago. JMF will probably not support all codec formats. That is probably why you are not able to play the file. There are also a lot of codec licensing issues.

There is a JMF performance pack for windows & *nix which will support more codecs than the default installation. Try that.  If that doesn't work take a look at [ffmpeg](http://fmj-sf.net/) or [VLC-J](https://code.google.com/p/vlcj/).

Comment: +1  I edited your answer in some trivial ways, in other ways not so trivial.  Please look over it & see if there is anything that you vehemently disagree with.  :-)

Comment: '`mp4`'  I'm pretty sure that **`mp3`** is supported, while `mp4` is not.  Even in the Performance Pack.  See the [Supported Formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) for more details.

Comment: Nothing I disagree with.  From what I remember mp3 support isn't there in the performance pack. It was packaged separately as a plugin. And Sun used to pull it out and replace it back occasionally citing licensing..  JMF2.1 is ancient..On the FAQ, its written that its Y2K compliant ;-)