# Java JMF won't play any video files

Tags: java, video, jmf

I try to play a video file (such as .avi) using the fabulous JMF 2.1.1, but I get the same error message:

`Unable to handle format: XVID, 624x352, FrameRate=23.9, Length=1317888 0 extra bytes
  Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 48000.0 Hz, 0-bit, Stereo, Unsigned, 18627.0 frame rate, FrameSize=9216 bits
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@e53108
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@e53108`
.

The program does play audio files. I am using a program I downloaded:

http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs778/spring04/lectures/jmfsolutions/MDIApp.java

and also tried the demo app from the Oracle interweb site. Codec problem seems likely, but I can't find any internet resources with specific instructions to remedy this. I am in dire need of help here. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: JMF is stinky dead fish, without any progress long time...

Comment: If you're not scared of JNI, there's always [libVLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/libvlc.html).

Comment: I got it to run with .mpg. I'm amazing that java doesn't have better built-in multimedia support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking from a previous question [How to create a media player in Java without JMF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146341/how-to-create-a-media-player-in-java-without-jmf). To be specific, there is a platform specific performance pack from Sun with some added codecs that might be useful. A list of [supported formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) is on the oracle site. But I don't think XVID will be supported